# Epimorphism, in the category of commutative rings with unity , with domain a field is an isomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, field-theory, epimorphisms

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $k$ be a field. Let $f: k \to R$ be an "epimorphism" of commutative rings  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism)
i.e. $f$ is   a ring homomorphism preserving unity and for any  commutative ring with unity $S$ and ring homomorphisms preserving unity $g,h: R \to S$, $g \circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$. Then is it true that $f$ is an isomorphism ?

I can see that $R$ has a $k$-algebra structure given by $f$ and also since $k$ is a field, $f$ is injective, so enough to prove that $f$ is surjective.   But I don't know how to approach further.

Comment: If $k\to S$ is an epimorphism and $k$ is a field, then $S=k$ or $S=0$. Lemma 10.106.8 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120918/are-epimorphisms-from-a-division-ring-isomorphisms

Comment: If $k\to k$ is an epimorphism, then it is an isomorphism by Lemma 10.106.7 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM, lemma which says that a faithfully flat epimorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: The answer is given is [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869367900671), see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120918/are-epimorphisms-from-a-division-ring-isomorphisms?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question "Let $f:k\to R$ be an epimorphism of commutative rings... Then is it true that $f$ is an isomorphism?" is No because the unique morphism $k\to0$ is an epimorphism.

The OP's statement that $f:k\to R$ is necessarily injective is not true.

If the intended question was "is it true that $f$ is surjective?", the answer is Yes, because a faithfully flat epimorphism is an isomorphism by Lemma 10.106.7 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM. Indeed any nonzero $k$-vector space is faithfully flat over $k$.

Comment: $k \to 0$ does not count as I have mentioned morphisms have to preserve unity and $1 \ne 0$

Comment: @users - It seems to me you didn't mention $1\ne0$. Do you agree that the usual definition of a commutative ring with one allows the possibility that $1$ is equal to $0$? Why do you want to impose $1\ne0$?

Comment: In commutative algebra usually we assume $1\ne 0$ ...

Comment: @users - I believe that Grothendieck has always allowed the possibility that $0=1$ in a commutative ring. Am I wrong? Even if I'm right, I don't know how Grothendieck would have justified this convention, but, for what it's worth, the first argument that comes to my very limited mind is that we want the category of commutative rings to have finite products.